# How to set the file polling frequency according to the Quartz cronExpression in mule

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio

I am very new to Mule.

I am facing a problem. I have a requirement where I need to read data from a CSV file which is in D:\ drive & insert data into PostgreSQL Database using Mule for every 2min.

So i have chosen Quartz.

Here is my code :

```
<configuration>
    <expression-language autoResolveVariables="true">
        <import class="org.mule.util.StringUtils" />
        <import class="org.mule.util.ArrayUtils" />
    </expression-language>
</configuration>

<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="jdbcDataSource" class=" ... your data source ... " />
</spring:beans>

<jdbc:connector name="jdbcConnector" dataSource-ref="jdbcDataSource">
    <jdbc:query key="insertRow"
        value="insert into my_table(col1, col2) values(#[message.payload[0]],#[message.payload[1]])" />
</jdbc:connector>

<quartz:connector name="myQuartzConnector" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Quartz">
  <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1"/>
</quartz:connector>

    <flow name="QuartzFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">

        <quartz:inbound-endpoint doc:name="Quartz"
            jobName="CronJobSchedule" cronExpression="0 0/2 * * * ?"
            connector-ref="myQuartzConnector" repeatCount="1">
            <quartz:event-generator-job>
                <quartz:payload>quartzSchedular started</quartz:payload>
            </quartz:event-generator-job>
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>


        <flow-ref name="csvFileToDatabase" doc:name="Flow Reference" />

    </flow>


<flow name="csvFileToDatabase">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="/tmp/mule/inbox"
        pollingFrequency="5000" moveToDirectory="/tmp/mule/processed">
         <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.csv" />
    </file:inbound-endpoint>

    <!-- Load all file in RAM - won't work for big files! -->
    <file:file-to-string-transformer />
    <!-- Split each row, dropping the first one (header) -->
    <splitter
        expression="#[rows=StringUtils.split(message.payload, '\n\r');ArrayUtils.subarray(rows,1,rows.size())]" />
    <!-- Transform CSV row in array -->
    <expression-transformer expression="#[StringUtils.split(message.payload, ',')]" />
    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="insertRow" />
</flow>
```

This is working fine but in D:\ if i keep csv file mule reading the csv file and writing to the database without waiting for 2 min(means Quartz scheduling time here).

If i set polling frequency of file connector with pollingfrequency="120000"(for 2 min 2*60*1000 milliseconds) also quartz is not waiting for 2 min.  Within the scheduling time of 2 min., if i place csv file in D:\  mule reading the csv file and writing to the database without waiting for 2 min(means Quartz scheduling time here).

Even if i place csv file in D:\,  mule Quartz has to perform action for every 2 min. only, for this  Which changes do i need to include here..

Could any one pls help me..

Answer (score 1):

It is because the flow csvFileToDatabase has its own inbound-enpoint that will execute regardless of the quartz flow. You have the  file:inbound-enpoint set to poll every 5000 milliseconds.

Theres no need to have both an inbound-endpoint and quartz scheduling the flow.

Either change the file:inbound-endpoint frequency or if you really want to use quartz to trigger the flow take a look at the mule request module that allows you to use an inbound-endpoint mid-flow: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester